# Implementation of a time lock with Python's asyncio

Tags: python, asynchronous, locking

I have no idea if this kind of lock is called time lock, but I need something for the following scenario: I'm making a lot of concurrent requests with `aiohttp`, and it's possible that the server at some point returns `429 Too Many Requests`. In that instance, I have to pause all my subsequent requests for some time.

I came up with the following solution:

```py
import asyncio


class TimeLock:

    def __init__(self, *, loop=None):
        self._locked = False
        self._locked_at = None
        self._time_lock = None
        self._unlock_task = None
        self._num_waiters = 0
        if loop is not None:
            self._loop = loop
        else:
            self._loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    def __repr__(self):
        state = f'locked at {self.locked_at}' if self._locked else 'unlocked'
        return f'[{state}] {self._num_waiters} waiters'

    @property
    def locked(self):
        return self._locked

    @property
    def locked_at(self):
        return self._locked_at

    async def __aenter__(self):
        await self.acquire()
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
        # in this time lock there is nothing to do when it's released
        return

    async def acquire(self):
        if not self._locked:
            return True
        try:
            print('waiting for lock to be released')
            self._num_waiters += 1
            await self._time_lock
            self._num_waiters -= 1
            print('done, returning now')
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            if self._locked:
                raise
        return True

    def lock_for(self, delay, lock_more=False):
        print(f'locking for {delay}')
        if self._locked:
            if not lock_more:
                # if we don't want to increase the lock time, we just exit when
                # the lock is already in a locked state
                print('already locked, nothing to do')
                return
            print('already locked, but canceling old unlock task')
            self._unlock_task.cancel()
        self._locked = True
        self._locked_at = time.time()
        self._time_lock = self._loop.create_future()
        self._unlock_task = self._loop.create_task(self.unlock_in(delay))
        print('locked')

    async def unlock_in(self, delay):
        print('unlocking started')
        await asyncio.sleep(delay)
        self._locked = False
        self._locked_at = None
        self._unlock_task = None
        self._time_lock.set_result(True)
        print('unlocked')
```

I am testing the lock with this code:

```py
import asyncio

from ares.http import TimeLock


async def run(lock, i):
    async with lock:
        print(lock)
        print(i)
        if i in (3, 6, 9):
            lock.lock_for(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = TimeLock()
    tasks = []
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for i in range(10):
        tasks.append(run(lock, i))
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
    print(lock)
```

The code produces the following output, which seems to be consistent with what I want from the above scenario:

```
[unlocked] 0 waiters
0
[unlocked] 0 waiters
1
[unlocked] 0 waiters
2
[unlocked] 0 waiters
3
locking for 2
locked
waiting for lock to be released
waiting for lock to be released
waiting for lock to be released
waiting for lock to be released
waiting for lock to be released
waiting for lock to be released
unlocking started
unlocked
done, returning now
[unlocked] 5 waiters
4
done, returning now
[unlocked] 4 waiters
5
done, returning now
[unlocked] 3 waiters
6
locking for 2
locked
done, returning now
[locked at 1559496296.7109463] 2 waiters
7
done, returning now
[locked at 1559496296.7109463] 1 waiters
8
done, returning now
[locked at 1559496296.7109463] 0 waiters
9
locking for 2
already locked, nothing to do
unlocking started
[locked at 1559496296.7109463] 0 waiters
```

Is the implementation correct, or can it be improved somehow?

*EDIT*: After doing a few experiments I think that the implementation works well. I am not sure about the thread-safety of this code though. I don't have too much experience with threads and asyncio code.